# Why this query filling the combo box with repeat value?

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I have these two tables in database.

```
tblProductSize(ID,SIZE_ID,PRODUCT_ID,COST_PRICE,SALE_PRICE)
tblSize(SIZE_ID,SIZE)
```

In query builder when I execute this Query

```
SELECT  tblSize.SIZE_ID AS Expr1, tblSize.SIZE FROM  tblProductSize INNER JOIN   tblSize 
ON tblProductSize.SIZE_ID = tblSize.SIZE_ID WHERE(tblProductSize.PRODUCT_ID = @product )
```

It shows me the exact values

```
SIZE_ID    SIZE
1          Small
2          Medium
3          Large
```

When I run this query to in C# using this code

```
public DataTable ReadCatWithProductID(int id)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    try
    {
        conn.Open();// 
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT  tblSize.SIZE_ID AS Expr1, tblSize.SIZE FROM  tblProductSize INNER JOIN   tblSize ON tblProductSize.SIZE_ID = tblSize.SIZE_ID WHERE(tblProductSize.PRODUCT_ID = " + id + ")", conn);
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        dt.Load(dr);

    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();

    } return dt;
```

and populate the values in a combo box like this

```
cmb.Items.Clear();
dlSize dlObj = new dlSize();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt = dlObj.ReadCatWithProductID(1);
cmb.DisplayMember = "SIZE";
cmb.ValueMember = "Expr1";
cmb.DataSource = dt;
```

It shows the result like this

[image]

Where I'm doing wrong thing Kindly guide me.

Comment: Can your table `tblProductSize` have multiple records for same product id?

Comment: @shell yes tblProductSize have multiple record for same ProductID

Comment: So, it is possible to return your query multiple duplicate records for different cost or price. You can use distinct for it

Comment: have you serialized an of your object

Comment: Verify very carefully you are using the _same_ database in both situations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this

```
conn.Open();// 
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Distinct tblSize.SIZE_ID, tblSize.SIZE FROM  tblProductSize INNER JOIN   tblSize ON tblProductSize.SIZE_ID = tblSize.SIZE_ID WHERE(tblProductSize.PRODUCT_ID = " + id + ")", conn);
SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
dt.Load(dr);
```

Comment: @Shell now it is not duplicating but it picks only two records niether the third?